# Karate how to parse this json string response

Tags: karate

I have a websocket response like below,

```
a["{\"type\":\"1ffe4b5d___AC_GET_MY_AVAILABLE_TASKS___N\"}"]
```

Can anyone tell me how to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Completely up to you, use string manipulation or use custom Java code if needed, I can only give you one hint:

```
* def response = 'a["{\"type\":\"1ffe4b5d___AC_GET_MY_AVAILABLE_TASKS___N\"}"]'
* json temp = response.substring(1)
```

And also see type-conversions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion